# Python urllib3 AWS Elastic Search ConnectionError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, python-requests, urllib3

I have written a python script that uses **elasticsearch** library to connect to AWS elastic search cluster. Things worked fine for sometime but suddenly started throwing **ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fec57c238e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fec57c238e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)**. 
 The error goes away when i restart the server but comes back after sometime. Can anyone help me resolve this? 
 
Posting the log for reference:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 245, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 379, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 735, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 309, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fec57c238e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: are you connected to VPN? This looks like a network issue more than code issue. You can try running tracert or ping to check the connectivity

Comment: I pinged the cluster from the server using curl. It seemed to work. Not sure what else could be wrong